# Manhwa where the main character fights a giant werewolf in a dungeon. Companion girl with short orange hair. Arrested mind control corrupted guy

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, powers

The main character fights a giant werewolf in an error in the dungeon. He has a female companion who has short orange hair. At some point, they sent a corrupt person who uses mind control into custody.

Comment: What do you mean by "an error in the dungeon"? Is there a glitch in the dungeon? Was that supposed to be another word?

Comment: Thank u for the comment but I already found the answer somewhere else with the same question I just gave. Don't even bother... Thx though

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - If it was meant to be another word, my money's on 'area.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ***[I Obtained a Mythic Item](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/itm1ceu/mythic-item-obtained)***.

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/mythic-item-obtained):

> In a world where technology and magic are almost indistinguishable from one another, monsters and creatures of myth and legend reign terror upon mankind. In humanity’s darkest moment, individuals with special god-like powers emerge to save the day. They are — the Awakened. Meet Jaehyeon, a feeble Awakened human Raider, who struggles to make ends meet until one day a series of confounding events allow him to claim a powerful item that will change the course of history forever…

This event happened in the middle part of the chapters. Hope this helps... and from what I know, the main character is a warrior who died and became a mage in the next one.